# Calculating number of variable arguments for clone function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, variadic-functions

I am trying to LD_PRELOAD the linux's `clone` function. In my LD_PRELOADed version I need to log  the input paramters before calling the original `clone` function. However, the problem is that `clone` takes variable number of arguments. It is declared like this.

```
int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack, int flags, void *arg, ...
/* pid_t *pid, struct user_desc *tls, pid_t *ctid */ );
```

Now to pass these arguments to the original `clone` function, I must know the number of arguments that were passed in. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you still happen to have that LD_PRELOAD code (or at least some skeleton)? Since I am trying to do exactly the same and also got stuck with the clone() varags. Regading the accepted answer, based on the implementation of va_* I think it will just eat-up (random) data on the stack. The caller must always tell the callee how much to use (number of arguments, terminator, format string or sth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a NULL terminator, you can call `va_arg` while it doesn't return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `va_*` functions, these are the way to go when working with variable argument lists.

Here's the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start) which also contains an example at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this is: You can't count the number of arguments in a variable arguments function.

However, for the `clone` function you can *assume* the number of arguments by looking at the `flags` argument, as certain flags require certain extra arguments.

Take for example the `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID` flag, in the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) it states:

> Store child thread ID at location *ptid* in parent and child memory. (In Linux 2.5.32-2.5.48 there was a flag CLONE_SETTID that did this.)

So if this flag is set then you know the `ptid` argument should exist, and you can use the [`va_*`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start) functions to get it.

However, there is no way of verifying that the user actually passed the argument which means if the user didn't then stuff could go horribly wrong.

Comment: So if CLONE_PARENT_SETTID is set you can assume ptid and eat one argument, if CLONE_SETTLS you can expect also tls and read 2 arguments from stack and if CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID or CLONE_CHILD_SETTID is set you can expect 3 arguments? This clone() is horribly hackish.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) describes the prototype such:

```
int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack, int flags,
          void *arg, ... /* pid_t *ptid, struct user_desc *tls, pid_t *" ctid ");
```

Note: I added a comma between the `tls` and `pid_t`, I think there's a typo in the manual page.

It then talks about the arguments `ptid` and `ctid`. So I'd go ahead and check the docs, and for those cases when those extra arguments are defined, that's how to read them off the `va_list`.